# 502 Bad Gateway (13 permission denied) Nginx + Gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to deploy a simple hello-world Django site to EC2 (Ubuntu 22.04) using Gunicorn and Nginx. Nginx and Gunicorn services are both reporting as running successfully, and the .sock file has been created seemingly without issue.

Gunicorn configuration file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=nextwork.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/sites/mysite-main
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-main-_EzVOJAm/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/sites/mysite-main/mysite-main.sock myapp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <domainname>.com <ipaddress>;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/sites/mysite-main;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/sites/mysite-main/mysite-main.sock;
    }
}
```

Permissions on the .sock file, as well as both the "sites" and "mysite-main" directories are `ubuntu:www-data`. I attempted to try moving it out of the ubuntu user's home directory into a more "common" location in case it was permissions on the home directory stopping it, but was unable to even get the .sock file to generate in that case, probably due to my unfamliarity with how this works.

It looks like this is one of the most queried problems of all time, but I've tried every solution I could find to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: line `proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/sites/mysite-main/mysite-main.sock;` remove `http://`

Comment: @J-JacquesM Thanks for the response; unfortunately that change triggers a "invalid URL prefix" error. It looks like I do need the `http://`.

Comment: make sure your nginx service process have rights to acces the socketcf: `chmod`, `chown`